# Initial Genesis difficulty on an ethereum clone

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain

I've created an ethereum clone that i hope someday can become a public blockchain. This is working good so far, however i have a question regarding the initial setup for once i set this live.

If i redo my chain (With the current difficulty on genesis.json of 0x20000) the blocks will be mined very fast and my only miner gets "Rich" with coins.

If this was a real case scenario and i wanted to launch this blockchain to the public would that be the only parameter i would have to set to ensure the first miners dont get ridiculously weatlhy?

Should i set it to the same difficulty that Ethereum would have at that same time and let the algorithm adapt by itself? or another value?

My goal is to prevent "whales" being created straight from the second the chain is launched.

Comment: there are a lot of Ethereum clones already, one better than another. Do your `market research` first

Comment: Unfortunately that doesnt answer my question,i know that many exist

Answer (score 0):

The miner will mine coins quickly only while the difficulty is low. However, as difficulty grows, the blockchain will emit 5 coins every 14 seconds and the mining paradise will be over.

You can set a high difficulty from the beginning (genesis block) and mining will be very slow from the start.